# Service Bus Explorer

Tags: service

Our project has Microsoft Service Bus (on-prem )  running on Windows 2012 R2 servers for message processing.
When sending messages to service bus topic above the size limit (say 10 mb )  ,  services bus shows processing error – throws socket timeout exception.

Just wanted to know ,

> if anyone has worked with sending messages (say > 10 MBs ) to Service Bus Topics . Would appreciate any suggested approach on how to handle this.
>   Also is there a way to increase the service bus timeout configuration or message size limit settings on Service Bus Topics either through Powershell cmds or Service Bus Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Service Bus queues support a maximum message size of 256 Kb (the header, which includes the standard and custom application properties, can have a maximum size of 64 Kb).

There is no limit on the number of messages held in a queue but there is a cap on the total size of the messages held by a queue. This queue size is defined at creation time, with an upper limit of 5 GB.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about sending a message which is of size 10 MB? Service Bus doesn't allow that large message. For Premium, the maximum message size is 1 MB, and for Standard, it's 256 KB as @Ana said.

> Also is there a way to increase the service bus timeout configuration
> or message size limit settings?

Yes, there is a possibility to handle time-to-live property of messages which can be configured either at the time of Queue/Subscription creation or while sending Individual message. [Refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-expiration) to set Time to live for Queue as well as message.

> Also is there a way to increase message size limit settings?

No, as the maximum size is 1 MB (May be increased by Azure in the future).

Answer (score 0):

To answer this "Can we Send messages (say > 10 MBs ) to Service Bus Topics".

Now as of today, the updated answer will be YES: The Premium tier of Service Bus, enabling Message size up to 100 MB.  Where as Standard is up to 256 KB as of today.

**How to enabling large messages support for an existing queue (or topic)**
[image]

Recommended:

- While 100 MB message payloads are supported, it's recommended to keep the message payloads as small as possible to ensure reliable performance from the Service Bus namespace.
- The Premium tier is recommended for production scenarios.